# Display data when changing selected value using JQuery / PHP

Tags: php, jquery, sql, select, request

Hope your are fine!

I'm would like to execute a request (SQL) like this one:

```
SELECT Name FROM course WHERE IdSectionFK = '.$idSectionFK.';
```

I have the list of sections:

```
while($row = $selectAllSection->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
   echo "<option value=".$row->IdSection.">".$row->Name."</option>";
}
```

And I would like to display the data only for the selected value. I tried something like this to get the value of the list:

```
<script>

function displayVals() {

        var idSection = $("#sectionListe").val();

        $.post('index.php', { 'idSection': idSection },function (){
          alert("success");
        })

        .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
        .error(function() { alert("error"); })
        .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
    }                                    

    $("select").change(displayVals);
    displayVals();

</script>
```

So, the variable "idSection" is equale to the PHP variable "idSectionFK" in my SQL request.
But how can I execute the right SQL request ?

Thank you so much for your help!

Lapinou.

Comment: you can use jquery.post -> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is the solution.

JS code:

```
function displayVals() {
    var idSection= $("#sectionListe").val();
    $("p").html(idSection);
    $.post('/url/to/php/file', { 'idSection': idSection }, function (response) {
        // do something with the response here
        // e.g: $('select').append(response);
        console.log(response);
    });
}                                    

$("select").change(displayVals);
displayVals();
```

PHP code to process the received data:

```
$idSectionFK = 0;

if (isset($_POST['idSection'])) {
    // get the ID from ajax, run SQL here
    $idSectionFK = intval($_POST['idSection']);

    $query = "SELECT Name FROM course WHERE IdSectionFK = '.$idSectionFK.';";

    // .... your code ...
}
```

Just to give you the basic idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help ;) But it doesn't work. I have no POST response... I don't understand why :/

Comment: Do you really need POST response? I haven't put that in the code before. Answer updated, could you check now?

Comment: No I don't. I mean, when I check if(isset($_POST['idSection'])), it always return false... Like if $.post doesn't work...

Comment: I edited my script to check it. It seems ok but $_POST['idSection'] is not set :/

Comment: Are you sure that `index.php` is the file contains the SQL query? Also any error in the console (using Firebug / Chrome dev tool)?

Comment: It's on the same page than the script (index.php). I checked with chrome dev tools, and yes, in fact, I have a POST method on index.php and idSection=1! But why the condition if(isset($_POST['idSection'])) doesn't work! Lol, really, it makes me crazy ^^

Comment: It should be `$.post(url)` and that url should be the file that has condition `if(isset($_POST['idSection']))`, I think `index.php` is something else

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33852/discussion-between-hieu-nguyen-and-lapinou)